# Unable to create a ValueProxy

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I am trying to create a `ValueProxy` which holds some basic information about a search a user is performing. For some reason GWT wants it to be an EntityProxy but I dont see why (nor does it make sense for this class to be an EntityProxy).

```
// FilterProxy extends ValueProxy
@ProxyFor(DayFilter.class)
public interface DayFilterProxy extends FilterProxy {

    void setFilterValue(Date day);
    Date getFilterValue();
}

public class DayFilter extends Filter {

    public DayFilter() {
        setOperator(FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL);
        setField("dateRequested");
    }

    public void setFilterValue(Date date) {
        this.value = date;
    }

    public Date getFilterValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public interface PaginationRequest<T> extends RequestContext {

    Request<List<T>> paginate(int offset, int limit, String sortColumn,
            boolean isSortAscending, List<FilterProxy> filters);

    Request<Integer> count(List<FilterProxy> filters);
}

@Service(value=TripService.class, locator=SchedgyServiceLocator.class)
public interface TripRequest extends PaginationRequest<TripProxy> {

    Request<TripProxy> save(TripProxy trip);
}
```

Within the activity that is sending this back to the server:

```
// Request is a TripRequest
DayFilterProxy filter = request.create(DayFilterProxy.class);
```

This results in:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: com.schedgy.trip.dao.filter.trip.proxy.DayFilterProxy is not an EntityProxy type
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.IdFactory.asEntityProxy(IdFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.IdFactory.createId(IdFactory.java:229)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.IdFactory.allocateId(IdFactory.java:41)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.create(AbstractRequestContext.java:478)
    at com.schedgy.trip.client.activity.TripsActivity.getFilters(TripsActivity.java:56)
```

Any ideas? Its got to be something obvious that I am just overlooking as I have ValueProxies working elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be that your DayFilterProxy is not referenced at all from the RequestContext?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the case. I am only referencing the base FilterProxy type in the RequestContext. I thought with GWT 2.4 we could have polymorphic params in request factory?

Comment: You have to add an `@ExtraTypes` annotation referencing them then: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactory_2_4#Polymorphism_support

Comment: @Brad I had to add public interface PaginationRequest<T extends ValueProxy>. If I don't do that I get the error "java.util.List<T> cannot be used here." It is the same if you have a EntityProxy instead of a ValueProxy. I am using GWT 2.5.1